# How to cast Menuitem to Button or imageButton

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

i want to cast Menuitem to button so i can set listener and perform action 
i have tried with custom **Actionbar** where i set imagebutton and perform a task
can anyone have please share it here

Comment: MenuiTem has their own listener.. why didn't you tried that

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   //getSupportMenuInflater() if you are using sherlock action bar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.urmenuxml, menu);
    MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(0);
    View anyView = new View();
    anyView.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    mi.setActionView(anyView);
    }
```

I hope this helps.